# Change printer per program in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, printer

Just for one specific program I want to set another default printer than for the other programs in windows xp.

My idea is to write a batch script which changes the default printer just for the program and start the program afterwards.

I tried

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "myprinter"
```

in the commandline for testing and watched the printer settings window at the same time. If I run the command above the checkmark for the default printer changes just for a second and switches then back.

I also tried http://www.chip.de/downloads/Automatic-Printer-Switcher-APS_43118387.html but it didn't recognize the progress I of my program.

How can I make my idea work? Is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: It should stay set after you run RUNDLL32, otherwise what is the point of using it. It certainly does so on my PC - but I'm running Win10, not XP. And, if there is a problem with permissions, it should not change even for a second. Here's a thought: try it in a batch file, and have a PAUSE on the next line. See if it will then stick until you press a key.